# I am getting an error while producing objects

Tags: c#, console-application, n-tier-architecture

I'm developing a project with N-tier architecture. I got errors while generating a new object in the main function.I can not give the features of car1. The entire text is underlined in red and I get these errors "CS1922: Cannot initialize type 'Car' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'" and "CS0747: Invalid initializer member declator".

```
using Business.Concrete;
using System;
using Entities.Concrete;
using DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework;

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        Car car1 = new Car
        {
            car1.Id = 4,
            car1.BrandId = 1,
            car1.ColourId = 2,
            car1.ModelYear = 1990,
            car1.Name = "King",
            car1.DailyPrice = 150,
            car1.Description = "Best"
        };

        CarManager carManager = new CarManager(new EfCarDal());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Entities\Concrete\Car.cs

```
using Core.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Entities.Concrete
{
    public class Car : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public int ColourId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ModelYear { get; set; }
        public int DailyPrice { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `car1.` access when initializing within `{}` like so:

```cs
        Car car1 = new Car
        {
            Id = 4,
            BrandId = 1,
            ColourId = 2,
            ModelYear = 1990,
            Name = "King",
            DailyPrice = 150,
            Description = "Best"
        };
```

Comment: I think it needs the parens tho too - new Car() { property=value }

Comment: @Nikki9696 it does. That's why I left them there.

Comment: You don't have parens (), you have brackets {}. Anyway, it's all good.  =)  Maybe it's not needed. Wasn't sure.

Comment: Oh those `()`. Yeah, you don't need them for empty constructor when you're also using `{}`.